# Is it possible to create a multiple Navigation Drawer/DrawerLayout on one side?

Tags: android, drawerlayout, navigation-drawer

I know this is possible with Sliding drawers but the answers posted here were too old and SlidingDrawer has already been deprecated. Anyway, I've setup mine using DrawerLayout using a CustomListAdapter with an ImageView populated by an array of image drawables.
[image: Android with DrawerLayout and a CustomListAdapter]
  
However, as you can see the drawer slides out altogether and presents us with 3 sidetabs.  What I'd like to see is for only one sidetab from among the 3 sidetabs to appear when called/touched/swiped.  Other requirements include:
* They must be clickable
* must have pressed/hover/default states (maybe selectors will do the trick for ImageButtons)
* The transparent background will not reveal the rectangular lines as shown above.

**Is there anyway to implement this in Android?**